# How to assign an IPv4 address to a second network interface of an LXC container?

Tags: networking, virtualization, lxc, network-bridge

I am running an lxc container which I want to connect to two different bridges (`br0` and `br1`). When I configure the container's config file (`/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/config`) as shown below, only the first interface is assigned an IP address:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:e6:16:c5

lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = br1
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:c5:16:c5
```

This is confirmed using `lxc-ls`:

```
NAME              STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4          IPV6 
testcontainer     RUNNING 1         -      192.168.1.6   -
```

And using `ifconfig` from within the container:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:e6:16:c5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fee6:16c5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:48388 (48.3 KB)  TX bytes:1576 (1.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:c5:16:c5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fec5:16c5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:521109 (521.1 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**Switching the order of the network interfaces inside the configuration file results in the other interface (which was previously unassigned) showing and IPv4 address.**

What is needed to be assigned an IPv4 on the second interface?

Answer (score 0):

Years late but you can add this other line:

```
lxc.network.ipv4 = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```